# how do I make get request directly to a flask app object

Tags: python, json, post, flask, get

I inherited a project that uses flask.  This flask application has several APIs, each API has a GET function that returns a json object.

I was asked to implement an additional API that requests information from the other APIs.  So my question is how do I make a GET request directly to a flask application?  Is it something like....

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/root_dir/api_number_1/info', methods=['GET'])
def request_info_from_api_number_1():
    return request.get_json()

@app.route('/root_dir/api_number_2/info', methods=['GET'])
def request_info_from_api_number_2():
    return request.get_json()
```

When I do this the functions return None.  I suppose I could always make an http request to the flask url and specify the address as localhost but it seems strange to have to make an http request when I can directly access the flask app object.

Comment: when you say you needed an additional API, do you mean another endpoint that returns the same data as the existing routes?  If so you can just add another decorator.

Comment: The new api does not return the same data as the existing apis.  However, it does need the data from the existing apis to do it's job.

Comment: It also seems you may be misunderstanding what the request object does and perhaps how the route() decorator works with url mapping.  If you paste some of your existing API code, I can try to help, or the flask docs are really good, so you can check them out.

Comment: I think I may be misunderstanding it and probably my code above is not the right way to do this.  I've been looking at the flask docs all afternoon and all I've found so far is how to make a http request to flask.  I was hoping there was a way to do this directly to the flask app object, without using http.  I have access to the actual flask app object in my python code already.

Comment: GET requests typically don't include JSON data. You'll usually only encounter that with POST and PUT requests. Query string parameters are exposed through `request.args` (a dictionary-like object).

Comment: Also, your use of `self` as an argument implies that your endpoints are methods on a class. If they are, please include the class definition. If they aren't, you should remove the argument since you don't have anything variable in your URLs mapped to it.

Comment: Seems I'm doing this wrong.  In both of my functions the request object only refers to the current request, which is going to the new api that I just created.  The request.url is going to /root_dir/my_new_api so it will always refer to that url regardless of my function decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use the existing api functions?

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/foo")
def foo():
    return "foo"

@app.route("/foobar")
def foobar():
    return foo() + "bar"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```